# Why I cannot use the Process.Start Method (String,String) inside using block in C#?

Tags: c#, process, using

I have an old program with this code block:

```
private void openConfigToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(a, b))) { writeConf(); }
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", Path.Combine(c, d));

}
```

I would like to optimize the code with `using` block, but I cannot declare 
Process.Start Method (String, String).

I tried this:

```
    private void openConfigToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(a, b))) { writeConf(); }

        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.Start("notepad.exe", Path.Combine(c, d)); //Problem
        }

    }
```

What is the problem with my program?

Comment: What is the problem exactly, is an exception being thrown? Are you getting compiler errors?

Comment: Yes. The problem is compile error.

Comment: If you are getting a compile error you need to edit your question and include the error message in your question.

Comment: @roll In the future please include the exact error message. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start method you used inside using block is static.

```
public static Process Start(string fileName, string arguments);
```

You have to call like

```
using (Process proc = new Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine(c, d);
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    proc.Start();
}
```